# gnu parallel error : "Expected a command, got perl"

Tags: gnu-parallel

I have been gnu parallel before but for some reason, it is not running anymore.
I have tried to uninstall and reinstall it without success.

Trying to run the parallel command gives the following error message.

```
Expected a command, got perl -- Check the available commands and options and syntax with 'help'
```

Comment: This does not sound like a problem with GNU Parallel but the system you are running this on. You need to tell us a lot more about the system you are doing this on. Can you run: `perl -e 1`? Can you run other programs written in perl (i.e. that start with "#!/usr/bin/perl")?

Comment: The error you get smells like Nextflow. Can you try without using Nextflow?

Comment: @OleTange Actually, Nextflow may be implied as this happens few times after installing it. Though I am just running `parallel` from the terminal, so I'am not sure where is Nextflow involved.

Comment: @OleTange as systems, I am using Windows Subsystem for Linux with Ubuntu"
16.04.3 LTS (Xenial Xerus). Linux version 3.10.0-514.6.1.el7.x86_64.

Comment: running `perl -e 1` is not returning anything.

Comment: Can you run: `perl $(which parallel) echo ::: foo`?

Comment: Yeah. It returns `foo`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110559/discussion-between-ole-tange-and-bnd).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `/usr/bin/env` may be broken. Try re-installing `coreutils`.